# Dynamic rule to change the color of a cell when a check box is true

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting, cell-format

The following code automatically links any CheckBox in the active sheet to one cell before the checkbox. In other words, I can add as many checkboxes as I want 
and when I run the code/macro, all checkboxes will be Linked to the cell before where the checkbox is located.

What I would like to be able to do, but I'm not sure how, is, be able to highlight the next two (2) cells (in front of each CheckBox) when the CheckBox is true. I can do that by creating a conditional rule but the way I'm doing it I would need to create a rule for each checkbox manually and I want a more dynamic rule since I want to be able to copy and paste checkboxes and be able to keep the functionality regardless of where the checkbox is located.

How can I modify the conditional rule or the macro in a way that `=$A$3` and `=$C$3:$D$3` (see picture) automatically change if the cells are copied and pasted to a different row?

### Macro

```
Sub LinkCheckBoxes()
Dim chk As CheckBox
Dim lCol As Long
lCol = -1 'number of columns to the right for link
For Each chk In ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes
   With chk
      .LinkedCell = _
         .TopLeftCell.Offset(0, lCol).Address
   End With
Next chk
End Sub
```

[image]

Please note that I will have a lot of checkboxes, similar to a TODO app and I want to be able to delete or add more if I need to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing `=$A$3` to `=$A3` did the trick. After this change, I can copy the row containing the checkbox, paste it then run the macro and everything works.

Answer (score 2):

You would need 2 rules to accomplish this.  One for true, one for false.

```
=IF(UPPER($A3)="TRUE",1,0)
```

This will apply conditional formatting for the True statements

```
=IF(UPPER($A3)="FALSE",1,0)
```

Likewise, for False  statements.

Putting the  '$' anchor on the 'A' allows the rule to be dragged horizontally to columns D and E without loosing the 'A' reference.  No anchor on the number lets it go to as many rows down as you need.

Comment: Thank you for your help. As I stated in my own answer, everything started working the way I wanted just by changing `=$A$3` to `=$A3`.